# Clean HTML and PHP For Loop Not Displaying Anything

Tags: php, html

```
   <?php for($x = 0; $x <= count($slides); $x++):?> 
                   <li data-target="#main-carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo($x);?>'" class="active"></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Not exactly sure what the error is everything seems right.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You didn't open with a `foreach` in the loop, but you are closing with `endforeach`?  Why not encapsulate the loop in `{ ... }` and omit the `endforeach`?

Answer (score 5):

You start yourself with a `for` loop, while closing it with a `foreach` loop. These are two very different things and cannot be matched like that.

You simply need to replace

```
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

with

```
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Alternatively, you can use curlybrackets `{` instead, having something like

```
<?php for($x = 0; $x <= count($slides); $x++) { ?>
    <!-- do HTML here -->
<?php } ?>
```